# File Server Resource Manager not moving expired files

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-server

I have setup a File Server Resource Manager task under Server 2008 R2.

The task has the following properties:
- Type: File expiration
- Scope: W:\Share\Company
- Expiration folder: S:\Archive
- Days since file was last modified: 1460 days (4 years)

The task runs, however "Expired" files are not being moved the to the Expiration folder. 
For example, a file with modified date "‎Thursday, ‎23 ‎February ‎2006, ‏‎2:42:27 PM" is not moved to S:\Archive.

Someone please help?

Comment: Same issue with 2012.  IF i go to the StorageReports folder i can see the job actually runs a report with the contents that do meet the criteria, in my report there are files (a majority of them) that show up as meeting the critera, but in the Expired directory all i see is a readme file.